# How to store array in usermeta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a custom form and am trying to store multiple values in the usermeta.  This is a sample code I am using, however it just stores the last option selected (i.e. if I select from Volvo to Opel, it will only store Opel in the database), whereas what I am wanting is all the values selected to be stored.  Im not sure what Im doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<select name="test" id="test" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    update_usermeta( $new_user, 'test', $_POST['test'] );
```

Comment: You'll want to post this over on [Wordpress SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?as=1) as this question seems specific to Wordpress.

Comment: `$_POST['test']` must be an array. You need to serialize it before storing.

Comment: OK thanks - I am a complete newbie to PHP, can you point me to where I can learn how to serialize it?

Answer (score 0):

according to the wordpress codex arrays and objects are automatically serialized

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

so you shouldn't have any problems with it. if you need to grab multiple values from the select you will need to treat it as an array name="test[]" like this

```
  <select name="test[]" id="test" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```